# capistrano allow carriage returns in output

Tags: ruby, capistrano

How can I allow carriage returns in the output of the capistrano task? I'm getting stuff like:

```
 ** [out :: ***.cloudapp.net] (Reading database ... 5%
 ** [out :: ***.cloudapp.net] (Reading database ... 10%
 ** [out :: ***.cloudapp.net] (Reading database ... 15%
 ** [out :: ***.cloudapp.net] (Reading database ... 20%
 ** [out :: ***.cloudapp.net] (Reading database ... 25%
 ...
```